# SSH remote execute command after using pbrun

Tags: linux, shell, ssh, remote-access, openssh

I am using a script that executes the following command in a bunch of servers:

```
sshpass -p password ssh -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no user@server 'sudo yum -y install NessusAgent.x86_64'
```

For most servers it works using sudo, but in some of them I only have **pbrun bash** for executing commands with privileges.

My issue is that when I make changes to the command:

```
sshpass -p password ssh -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no user@server 'pbrun bash; yum -y install NessusAgent.x86_64'
```

It just hangs up in there and I get no response until I just hit CTRL-C to kill it. I tried ssh with -t flag, but it puts me straight into the target server's shell and that's not what I want.

Is there a way to use pbrun and execute the command without the issues I am experiencing?

Comment: I"m not familiar with `pbrun`, but `pbrun bash;` seems to me that you're opening a bash shell and waiting for input. I bet you could type `/bin/ls -l` and get a response. Not sure how to get around this. Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have never used power broker, but I think your problem is the `;` ...

Can you try:

```
'pbrun bash -c "yum -y install NessusAgent.x86_64"'
```

instead of your

```
'pbrun bash; yum -y install NessusAgent.x86_64'
```